# RDP on Linux system

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, rdesktop

I want to know more about how Remote Desktop Protocol works on Linux system. Does RDP client on Linux (rdesktop, FreeRDP, etc) using same API as Windows remote desktop?

Answer (score 0):

RDP is a proprietary Microsoft protocol.  A good starting point would be the [MSDN RDP documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc240445.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to know how RDP works, you can check [FreeRDP project](http://www.freerdp.com/) which is a free implementation of the Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP). You can check the source code at [GitHub](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP) or check its [API documentation](https://pub.freerdp.com/api/). It works on Linux, macOS and Windows.